# What is the best approach to dynamically rebuilding an live (MVC 3) Website

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I do not think it matters that my question pertains to a MVC 3 website but I mention it anyway.

OK. I have a subDomain MVC 3 website in *** PRODUCTION *** , eg. "dowork.mydomain.com".

I am dynamically creating areas for each customer who logs on. (no prob with that).

If a customer is in his area, eg."dowork.mydomain.com/customer1234/", and doing work on his account, while a new area is being added to the app for a new customer who joins in, eg. dowork.mydomain.com/customer5678", to then which MSBuild.exe is called to update that new area to the live website, does the customer1234 incur any errors during/after that rebuild?

Is this the feasible approach, or would I be better off creating a dynamic subdomain for each logon (customer1234.mydomain.com) to prevent any errors 1234 would incur when customer5678.mydomain.com is dynamically created?

Comment: Are you dynamically generating code when the user logs in or are _you_ writing and deploying code when a new customer signs up?

Comment: this is not a sign up, this is for existing customers, but the Areas created for each customer are temp and dynamic, so cust1234's area name changes (eg cust1234_May102010 - something like that). My concern is whether other customers already on their dynamic and temp created areas will have problems "doing work/hitting DB" while a rebuild of the entire subdomain is made when other existing customers have a dynamic and temp area created for them to do work.

Comment: please clarify the areas you are referring to are these the applications resources that the user can access or the user profiles in mvc you can define routes for the users that routes can point to the ActionResults and on basis of your business logic you can present the view to each customer

Comment: I create a Controller called "UpdateEmailAccount.cs" and it has a view, and view model named accordingly. I have these pre-canned files stored somewhere. When I create a new area for customer1234, and copy those canned files to his area, and then a rebuild, he goes along and manages his email account. Now customer5678 logs on, I create an area for him and copy those canned files to his area so he can manage his email account. I have to rebuild dynamically for 5678's area to be useable. When I do that is 1234 going to incur any errors if he was doing work while the rebuild was happening?

Comment: John: Are you saying I should 86 the entire dynamic area concept and add a custId parameter in same controller for all customers?

Comment: If you use, dynamic subdomain, you can create routes accordig to that and the customer can be verified using his subdomain. In this way you need not rebuild your application since you are using only subdomains dynamically. It is more feasible since the risk of rebuilding is avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't fully understand your requirements, but rebuilding the website will cause the application to restart, which has serious scalability and performance implications.

> When I do that is 1234 going to incur any errors if he was doing work
>   while the rebuild was happening?

1234 *shouldn't* incur any errors since their request should finish running on the existing appdomain before the build started, but depending on the size of the files and the dependencies you may need to tweak the [httpRuntime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx) maxWaitChangeNotification and waitChangeNotification settings that control when the appdomain is started anew.

You may want to rethink how you've architected your system and rely instead on a more flexible and dynamic system that uses URL rewriting or dynamic routing along with a shared data driven view.